# LTspice param, resistor

Tags: resistors, ltspice

Is this correct answer for question given?

Parameterize one of the resistors and investigate the effect of the size of this resistor on the output voltage if the input voltage is 10V and the resistance R changes in the range of 0.1 to 10 times the original value of R with a step 0.01R.
[image]

Comment: Try .step Rx list

Comment: I mean, is that really necessary? If I understand it correctly, list gives use exact given values to sweep while I just want to use initial value and go from 0.1 to 10

Comment: You need multiple plots. A list is one way of doing it but you can do the incremental .step param Rx 0.1 1 0.01.

Comment: Okay, I have changed it to .step param but the graph looks kind of similar, is that alright?

Comment: Oh! Sorry about that. You sweeped the entire range in one analog swoop. You could pick out the 99 points from your original graph if you wanted. As there are no dynamics in the circuit and if your teacher wants a list and not a graph, you can use the .meas and pick the results from the error log, but you need to use steps for it to work.

Comment: I need a graph not a list to be specific

Comment: Then your job is done.

Comment: Thank you! You have really helped me a lot

Comment: Maybe you could also go to check my temperature graph in another question! I would have been really thankful. @winny